# How to get target_link_libraries throw miss or errors

Tags: cmake

I'm using "modern cmake" with packages and would like to get errors when target_link_libraries is missing a library.

I have one CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(libB
    sourceB.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(libB
    PRIVATE libC
)
```

and this one in an other directory

```
add_library(libC
    sourceC.cpp
)

target_include_directories(libC
    PUBLIC include # Will provide include/sourceC.h
)
```

In sourceB.cpp, I'm including sourceC.h

Here I forget to add the add_subdirectory to libC so when I build, I get this error:

```
sourceB.cpp:2:10: fatal error: sourceC.h: No such file or directory
```

How instead of this compile time error, can I ask cmake to throw me a miss error because I specifically ask to link with libC but never gave him libC ?

I saw add_dependencies but don't necessarily want libC to be built before libB

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to check if it's a target. Probably somewhere on the end of your file, at least after `add_subdirectory(libC)`

```
if(NOT TARGET libC)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Och nuu, libC is not a target")
endif()
```

A *great* solution would be to implement a `target_link_targets` functionality, which would allow linking only with targets. While sounds trivial, it's not so easy - static libraries can be linked circular and can be before they are defined. So you have to check if all are targets on the end of CMake file after we know every target is defined.

I did such implementation, [my implementation is available here](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/kcmakelib/-/blob/master/cmake/k/target_link_targets.cmake#L27). The function `k_target_link_targets` checks if all arguments are targets. From CMake 3.19.0 it uses `cmake_language(DEFER` to defer execution of a checking function to the end of CMake scripts, before 3.19.0 a manual call to `k_target_link_targets_check` function is needed on the end of a CMake file.

Comment: The `cmake_language` command was added in v 3.18, but the `DEFER` was added in v 3.19. At least that's what the docs say: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_language.html#defer